# Browser pop-up pop-under, tab-over, tab-under support

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am doing a POC around browser window. I want following behaviors when a new browser window is opened.

1. Pop-up: New window should have focus
2. Pop-under: Parent window should have focus
3. Tab-over: New Tab should have focus
4. Tab-under: Parent Tab should have focus
   Out of these 4, Pip-up and Tab-over are supported by Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Any one know if other two are supported by these browsers or not ?
Any implementation links would be helpful. I an doing this POC using Javascript and JQuery.